# using iterator to erase element in vector

Tags: c++, vector, erase

I have the following vector to store elements of type player:

```
std::vector<player> players;
```

in a class called game which has the following function:

```
void game::removePlayer(string name) {
  vector<player>::iterator begin = players.begin();

  // find the player
  while (begin != players.end()) {
      if (begin->getName() == name) {
          break;
      }
      ++begin;
  }

  if (begin != players.end())
      players.erase(begin);
```

}

I get the following error:

```
    1>------ Build started: Project: texas holdem, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  game.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(2514): error C2582: 'operator =' function is unavailable in 'player'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility(2535) : see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt std::_Move<_InIt,_OutIt>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt,std::_Nonscalar_ptr_iterator_tag)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _OutIt=player *,
1>              _InIt=player *
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\vector(1170) : see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt std::_Move<player*,player*>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _OutIt=player *,
1>              _InIt=player *
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\vector(1165) : while compiling class template member function 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec> std::vector<_Ty>::erase(std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Myvec>)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Myvec=std::_Vector_val<player,std::allocator<player>>,
1>              _Ty=player
1>          ]
1>          c:\vcprojects\texas holdem\texas holdem\game.h(29) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<_Ty>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=player
1>          ]
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

removing the line

```
players.erase(begin);
```

fixes the error, why is it happening though and how can I fix it?

Comment: As a style note, I'd choose a name other than `begin` for your iterator since I believe it's easy for a reader to confuse with the well-known name `begin()`. For example, when I saw the line `players.erase(begin);` my first thought was, "why is he erasing the first element instead of the matching element?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to overload the assignment operator `Player & operator= (const Player & other)` for your class Player. This required because `erase` requires it's argument to be copyable (it needs to rearrange the other elements of the vector after removal).

Comment: Correct, but be careful with the word "movable". Prior to C++11 it was fine, but now it implies that a class supports move semantics. While that's useful for vector::erase(), it's not required. An ordinary assignment operator is sufficient. The terminology these days is "copyable" and "movable".

Comment: Pedantic note: C++03 requires that all types used with containers be copy constructable and assignable (in general), regardless of the operations you might perform on the container.  C++11 is less strict - the requirements on the contained type depend specifically on the operations you perform with the container.  For `vector::erase()`, the contained type must be 'MoveAssignable'.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that the library code removes the `player` object by shoving each of the array elements above that iterator down one slot. To do that, it copies each object, using operator=. Apparently the class `player` doesn't have that operator.

Comment: And, having just pointed out to @cmh how "movable" has changed meaning in C++11, I see that I used "moving" above. Sigh.

Comment: On the plus side, I feel a little less bad.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `Player` class is not movable. In order to remove a `Player` from the middle of the vector, all the `Player`s after that have to be moved down one space in the vector. One solution is not to use a vector. Another is to make `Player` movable.